# I have been personally attacked (by getting unexplained downvotes for multiple questions at once)

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

Yesterday I decided to downvote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1137377/107671) (by the user [induktio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/191378/induktio?tab=summary)) for reasons I clearly stated in the comments.

The answerer omitted some details when performing a not-always-invertible operation to both sides of an equation and performed it while not taking into account any possible extraneous or missing solutions that could result from such an operation being made to both sides of an equation.

He disagreed that that was a reasonable downvote and then suddenly a few of my questions that had clear work shown on my part and did not deserve downvotes got 2 downvotes each ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805330/if-a4b4-in-mathbb-q-and-a3b3-in-mathbb-q-and-a2b2-in-mathbb-q-pr) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642072/find-all-x-y-z-in-mathbb-n-x-y-z1-such-that-satisfy-x-mid-yz1-y-mid-x)), one of them got 3 downvotes ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620086/if-n-in-mathbb-n-and-4n2n1-is-prime-prove-that-there-exists-an-m-in-ma)).

One of my answers that I think answered the question as it should have ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1132241/107671)) also got 2 downvotes, but at the very least the downvotes were explained in the comments even though I might disagree with them (I'm not claiming some more explanation could not change my mind though, but I currently disagree). But I appreciate that they were at least *attempted to be explained*, while a mass of others *were not*.

The user I downvoted, [induktio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/191378/induktio?tab=summary), also added that he did not appreciate my voting history, which I assume was the upvote:downvote ratio (which is 1,376 : 80 at the moment I am writing this), while his own upvote:downvote ratio is 312 : 228 at the moment I am writing this.
Thus he downvotes a *lot* more than I do and thus he does not even appreciate his *own* voting history *even more* if he claims he does not appreciate mine, which is nonsense and which makes his argument invalid, since he would not downvote so much knowing he does not appreciate such actions.

While Karl, the other answerer, *did* do the same mistake, I had not read his answer before today, and when I noticed that indeed another person has done the same mistake, I decided to remove the downvote and leave Karl's answer without a downvote but with a comment that emphasizes how important it is not to avoid the details when performing such not-always-invertible operations to both sides of an equation.

What is your opinion about all these attacks by unexplained downvotes that I got after downvoting for legitimate mistakes that might not be as crucial to the particular problem but could easily be when you consider doing such not-always-invertible operations to both sides of an equation in general, e.g., squaring both sides of an equation, etc.?
Am I doing something wrong or are the others doing something wrong?

**Edit:** I want to report that posting this question has caused 5 more downvotes, even to 2 questions [I showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615968/if-x-y-z-in-mathbb-r-setminus-1-and-xyz-1-prove-that-fracx2x-1) a [huge amount of work in](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615630/prove-that-if-x-1-x-2-ldots-x-n0-then-1x-11x-1x-2-ldots1x-1x-2), among others is a [correct answer I've posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1012183/107671). None of these new downvotes were explained.

**Edit2:** Thanks to [SE software](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), serial downvotes by 2 users have all been reversed. One of the users downvoted 9 of my posts and the other downvoted 3 of my posts.

Comment: Meta is not the place to bring up personal issues. If you want to do something, you can flag the posts for moderator attention instead and explain the issue. Personally, I would just move on.

Comment: Move on, life goes on!

Answer (score 4):

The correct thing to do when you suspect some sort of untoward voting is to flag one of the posts and ask a moderator to investigate. There is nothing that anyone else can do (actually, the moderators' abilities are also limited).

Posting about downvotes on meta is discouraged not because all votes are reasonable, but because there is nothing anyone here can really do about them.